# pandas module to trim columns in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Any idea why below code can't keep the first column of my csv file? I would like to keep several columns in a new csv file, first column included. And if I select the name of first column to be on new file.
 I get an error :

> "Type" not index.

```
import pandas as pd
f = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
keep_col = ['Type','Pol','Country','User Site Code','PG','Status']
new_f = f[keep_col]
new_f.to_csv("2.csv", index=False)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "type" and "Type" are two different things. Are you using the right one?

Comment: Could you please provide some input data? First 3 rows (with header) of raw CSV and first 3 rows (with header) of `f` dataframe. Thx!

Comment: @user2539738 yes I am. The correct is Type. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `f.columns.values.tolist()` and check the output of the first column.  It sounds like there is an encoding issue when you are reading the CSV.  You can try specifying the "encoding" option in your `pd.read_csv()` to see if that will get rid of the extra characters at the front.  Otherwise, you can use `f.rename(columns={'F48FBFBFType':'Type'}` to change whatever the current name of your first column is to simply be 'Type'.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off by specifying the columns to read from your csv file.

```
pd.read_csv('1.csv', names=keep_col).to_csv("2.csv", index=False)
```

Do you have any special characters in your first column?